# How do I get Items in between items of list?

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with my code.

Let's say I have a list:

`[name,A,name1,B,name2,name3,C, name5, notname]`

I want the loop to get all the names after the alphabets A,B and C. I'm a bit confused on how I should do that. Any ideas?

So far I have tried an if statement. If in the loop A is detected it will iterate to the next index via i+=1

So:

```
 string = ''  
 for i in range(o, len(list_)):

       if(list_[h] == 'A'):
           while list_[h]!='B':
                  string+=list_[h]
                  i+=1
```

but with this code im getting the other values instead. I also want to get the names under B and C until it stops at `notname`

Expected output is to concatenate all strings in between alphabets:

```
A: name1
B: name2name3
C: name5
```

excluding `notname` at all cost

Comment: You could try iterating through a list which contains the alphabet, then match those in the if statement. This method is a bit of a hack however, and not a general solution. As for the stopping, you can add an if else statement which checks the string and breaks if found.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Get the index of the element C first and then iterate over the list from that index onwards to get the following names

Comment: @ZWang I tried deleting other values than those that have alphabets if that is what you meant. I also tried getting a separate list per alphabet and then storing all the items before the next one. But it's not going well. The hard part is determining the **start** index and then strictly ending it the last index where other chars arent needed

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar I expect to concatenate all strings that are in between the alphabets except the noise `notname`

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar I added the expected output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
names  = ['name','A','name1','B','name2','name3','C', 'name5', 'notname']
keys = ['A','B', 'C']

result={}
current=''
for i in names:
    if i in keys:
        current = i
        result[current] = []
    elif current and i!='notname':
        result[current].append(i)
```

Then the result will be:

```
 {'A': ['name1'], 'B': ['name2', 'name3'], 'C': ['name5']}
```

Try to print it like this:

```
for k,v in result.items():
    print(k +': ' +''.join(v) )
```

Comment: your welcome @dekt, please consider this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Not a general solution, but you can try

```
namelist = ['name1','A','name2','B','name3','name4','C', 'name5', 'notname']
alphabets = set(['A','B','C'])
result = {}
start = None
for index, item in enumerate(namelist[:-1]):
    if(item in alphabets):
        if(start):
            result[namelist[start-1]] = ''.join(namelist[start:index])
        start = index+1
result[namelist[start-1]] = ''.join(namelist[start:index+1])
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks but it only excludes `notname` and the end result are the same list before it was put into the loop. I added the expected output on the question